# Action link click event cannot be prevented in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following javascript function for deleting items:

```
function deleteItem(itemName){
    var confirmDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + itemName + "?");
    if (!confirmDelete) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Tried with preventDefault
        return false; //Tried with return false
                      //Tried with both
    }
}
```

And I use this function in several ActionLinks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { route values here }, new { onclick = "deleteItem('" + ItemToDeleteName + "');"})
```

It works correctly on IE and Chrome but not in FireFox. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `return` like

```
new { onclick = "return deleteItem('" + ItemToDeleteName + "');"}
```

Also, You should return `true/false` from your function `deleteItem()` based on which execution will continue or break

Comment: Thanks! It worked with return true/false from function. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @vortex, Glad it worked, I was in a fix with your previous comment

Comment: @Saptal, would you explain me in short why is this behaviour in FireFox? I mean preventDefault() worked for other major browsers, but not for FireFox.

Comment: @vortex, I am sure event must be undefined, as you are not passing it to onclick event handler. To confirm it just log it use `console.log(event)` then see the result

Comment: @Saptal, you are completely right. From firefox console: `event is not defined` Thanks once again!